# Is there a better way to solve this jenkins problem

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

tried doing contnuous deployment and had the following error message after giving write permisions to tomcat directory

[image: 1]

Comment: What do you mean with better way? How did you solve the problem? If problem is solved, what is the question?

Comment: is there a way to solve this problem. problem not solved

Comment: Every problem can be solved. What did you try to solve it? What didn't work?

Comment: tried by giving tomcat8 write permissions but still had no success